# NestJS: Pipe not applied to bound body parameters

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

I'm trying to find a decent way to validate the schema differently for the same object. That is how I got familiar with the ***groups*** `validationOption` from the **class-validator**.

According to the NestJS Body param doc, it states

> Also applies pipes to the bound body parameter.

I have an Event model that has a **status** property. While creating an Event `(POST - /events)`, the status is *optional*, but when updating the status `(PATCH- /events/:id/status)`, its *mandatory*.

```
@Entity("events")
export class Events {
  @IsString({ groups: ["updateStatus"] })
  @IsNotEmpty({ groups: ["updateStatus"] })
  @IsOptional({ groups: ["createOne"] })
  @IsEnum(EventStatus, { groups: ["updateStatus"] })
  @Column({
    type: "enum",
    enum: EventStatus,
    default: EventStatus.OPEN
  })
  status: EventStatus;

  // ...other properties also.
}
```

When I made an update request to status, I provide the `@Body` with `'status'` as a param and **ValidationPipe** as pipe option.

```
@Patch('/:id/status')
async updateStatus(
    @Body(
         'status',
         new ValidationPipe({
             groups: ['updateStatus'],
         }),
    )
    status: EventStatus
) {
// Business logic.
}
```

But with this code, it's not validating the status field according to its group mentioned. Anyone knows what wrong I'm doing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.